# Netbeans Java: Why is my Java with ANT project .jar executable was able to run meanwhile my Java with Maven could not

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, build, jar

I have made a program using NetBeans and using its JFrame customization. The program would be used for storing grocery products data. put the product name, price, VAT, etc and it will calculate the markup and VAT and print its output into a text file. I decided to upgrade my skills and attempt to create an output with an Excel file .xlsx to look more profesional. So I searched Youtube tutorials and turns out you have to build a new Java with Maven project and use pom.xml to add dependencies and libraries that are needed to create a Workbook. With tweaks to its design, code, and success! Now I just have to build the program to an executable .jar file

I was expecting it to run like my old program but it won't open. The old version that spits a .txt file and doesn't need any dependency opens like normal. But my newer one won't and I have no idea how to debug it.

1. I tried opening the old program if there is something wrong with my Java installation fortunately there wasn't and the old program runs.
2. I tried removing all the apache. poi dependencies on my file build it only with its GUI and no functionality and build a jar file. It won't open.
3. I tried to move that into a project on Java With Ant (where my old program was) and remove all it's maven dependencies and related code and function only the base GUI. it runs! but I cannot create inputs or an excel worksheet.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.groupself</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProductPricesLister</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
            <type>pom.sha512</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.groupself.productpricelister.GroceryProductsLister</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for manual attach debugging -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run@debug -->
                        <id>debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=localhost:8000</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE debugging -->
                        <id>ide-debug</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Configuration for automatic IDE profiling -->
                        <id>ide-profile</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <options>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg1}</option>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg2}</option>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg3}</option>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg4}</option>
                                <option>${profiler.jvmargs.arg5}</option>
                            </options>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: What os you are using?Have you tried running your program from terminal or only netbeans?

Comment: I use windows 10, I tried to run the  program only on netbeans. I built it on netbeans aswell. I only used Maven because of the tutorial.

Comment: Try to run in the command line may help you get more output of the error.But it looks like your missing a manifest.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/manifest-customization.html

Comment: how do I do that? running in the command line you mean to say cmd?

Comment: Command prompt on windows i think. Open command prompt in the directory the jar is in type java your-app.jar press enter.I use linux so im no command prompt expert but give it a try.

Comment: so it just opens the program but it isn't showing any errors

Comment: yes, I opened the cmd file at the target folder where the jar is. what happens is if I used the old ANT version with the command, it just runs like double-clicking it, the gui appears aswell as the function. Meanwhile the newer one just like activates the command and makes a new line. No program GUI opens like the program stops overall. 

With the manifest file you linked I haven't added them because I think it would ocnflict with

 ```<configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>``` ?

Comment: Any file I make with Maven and built with maven using net beans clean and build results in a program not opening.

Comment: Do I have to install Maven like java?and add an environment varaible?

Comment: I have another calculator program with a maven instead of ANT. like my 2nd grocery price lister. If I run it in IDE it works but failts to run as a .jar file unlike ant.

Comment: Which maven version are you using?

Comment: mvn -v from command line will check maven version. java -version also from command line to get java version.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer it seems. you have to add some plugins just to make it run an executable manifest then collect all dependencies. the maven version is 4.0.0.
there is a new  encapsulation aswell as cleanup on dependencies.

````
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.groupself</groupId>
    <artifactId>ProductPricesLister</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>com.groupself.productpricelister.GroceryProductsLister</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.groupself.productpricelister.GroceryProductsLister</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>                         
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>```
````